# RAM and Windows 7, how much do I need?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How much RAM do I need for Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what you were planning on doing with Windows 7 ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The official answer from the company which produces Windows7 is:

```
2 GB of RAM.
```

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements

Some folks had some fun and went down to [512 MB of RAM](http://www.neowin.net/news/main/09/05/22/windows-7-how-low-can-it-go), but I would stay on the 2 GB minimum to have at least a half decent running system.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what software you're going to run. 
4 GB are a minimum IMHO. If you can afford more, go for it (RAM is cheap and it's one of the easiest ways to speed up your system).

My notebook currently has 6 GB, but it runs 2 VMs.

**[Windows 7 system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements)**

Comment: "4 GB are a minimum"?!?! far from it! 2GB is more than enough. while 64bit gives the advantage of using 4GB or more, its not a requirement (check the link you posted).
Of course its always better to get more RAM if you can, but a minimum for a smoothly working system with Win7 is 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 runs just fine on my Netbook with 1 GB RAM. For more than just Office and Browsing 2 GB might be a good investment though.